# Smartarray hpacucli command not showing individual drive status

Tags: ubuntu, hp, hp-smart-array, drive-failure

Having a problem with the HPACUCLI cmd on linux, at boot a hp p600 card is reporting an error, but I'm unable to determine which drive it is.

Instead of listing the separate drive status, I get one drive status repeated for the array

Smart Array P600 in Slot 6

array A

```
  Logical Drive: 1
     Size: 7.3 TB
     Fault Tolerance: RAID 6 (ADG)
     Heads: 255
     Sectors Per Track: 32
     Cylinders: 65535
     Stripe Size: 128 KB
     Status: OK
     Array Accelerator: Enabled
     Parity Initialization Status: Initialization Failed
     Unique Identifier: 600508B10010424246525646544B0013
     Disk Name: /dev/cciss/c0d0
     Mount Points: /mnt/areca3 1.3 TB
     Logical Drive Label: A055C2D0P92B30BBFRVFTKC248
```

=> ctrl slot=6 pd all show detail

Smart Array P600 in Slot 6

array A

```
  physicaldrive 0:0
     Box: 0
     Bay: 0
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SATA
     Size: 2000.3 GB
     Firmware Revision: 01.01D02
     Serial Number:      WD-WCAY01058382
     Model: ATA     WDC WD2003FYYS-0
     SATA NCQ Capable: False
     PHY Count: 1
     PHY Transfer Rate: 1.5GBPS
  physicaldrive 0:0
     Box: 0
     Bay: 0
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SATA
     Size: 2000.3 GB
     Firmware Revision: 01.01D02
     Serial Number:      WD-WCAY01058382
     Model: ATA     WDC WD2003FYYS-0
     SATA NCQ Capable: False
     PHY Count: 1
     PHY Transfer Rate: 1.5GBPS
  physicaldrive 0:0
     Box: 0
     Bay: 0
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SATA
     Size: 2000.3 GB
     Firmware Revision: 01.01D02
     Serial Number:      WD-WCAY01058382
     Model: ATA     WDC WD2003FYYS-0
     SATA NCQ Capable: False
     PHY Count: 1
     PHY Transfer Rate: 1.5GBPS
  physicaldrive 0:0
     Box: 0
     Bay: 0
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SATA
     Size: 2000.3 GB
     Firmware Revision: 01.01D02
     Serial Number:      WD-WCAY01058382
     Model: ATA     WDC WD2003FYYS-0
     SATA NCQ Capable: False
     PHY Count: 1
     PHY Transfer Rate: 1.5GBPS
  physicaldrive 0:0
     Box: 0
     Bay: 0
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SATA
     Size: 2000.3 GB
     Firmware Revision: 01.01D02
     Serial Number:      WD-WCAY01058382
     Model: ATA     WDC WD2003FYYS-0
     SATA NCQ Capable: False
     PHY Count: 1
     PHY Transfer Rate: 1.5GBPS
  physicaldrive 0:0
     Box: 0
     Bay: 0
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SATA
     Size: 2000.3 GB
     Firmware Revision: 01.01D02
     Serial Number:      WD-WCAY01058382
     Model: ATA     WDC WD2003FYYS-0
     SATA NCQ Capable: False
     PHY Count: 1
     PHY Transfer Rate: 1.5GBPS
```

=> ctrl slot=6 show config

Smart Array P600 in Slot 6                (sn: P92B30BBFRVFTK)

array A (SATA, Unused Space: 0 MB)

```
  logicaldrive 1 (7.3 TB, RAID 6 (ADG), OK)

  physicaldrive 0:0 (box 0:bay 0, SATA, 2000.3 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 0:0 (box 0:bay 0, SATA, 2000.3 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 0:0 (box 0:bay 0, SATA, 2000.3 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 0:0 (box 0:bay 0, SATA, 2000.3 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 0:0 (box 0:bay 0, SATA, 2000.3 GB, OK)
  physicaldrive 0:0 (box 0:bay 0, SATA, 2000.3 GB, OK)
```

=>

Suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen in certain setups, especially with really disparate components. E.g. the [Smart Array P600 RAID controller](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/proliantstorage/arraycontrollers/smartarrayp600/) was never meant to be used with 2TB SATA disks; and probably not Western Digital disks.

Either way, please output the result of `ctrl all show config detail`.

- Can you please share what enclosure the drives are in?
- Is this an HP server? If so, what model and generation?
- Since you receive a post message at boot, the drive ID and slot would be reported there.
- If this is any sort of HP enclosure or internal drive cage, the drive LED for a failed disk or prefailure condition should be illuminated.

---

You're on Ubuntu. Most of the troubleshooting methods I have depend on the answers to the above questions. For instance, the individual drive bay health on an HP system will also be reflected in the ILO... But if this is not an HP server or a model without ILO, that's not an option.

Your issue may just be the parity initialization error listed in your output. The size of the drives and whether this was a recent boot following a new installation may mean something. Also controller firmware... But fill in the details first.